# Odoo: How to remove notebook pages in sales order

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

How do i remove or modify these notebook pages in sales order, i searched for them in addons/sale/views/sale_views.xml but didn't find them

[image]

Comment: Yes, because it was coming from inherited views. So, you need to check that from where it is coming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not remove the pages from the form view because it is inherited from other views also.

Instead, you can make it `invisible` by inheriting the `view_order_form` of sale.

```
       <record id="view_order_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">sale.order.form</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
            <field name="priority">20</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//page[@name='other_information']" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//page[2]" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <!--remove the notebook pages-->

        <xpath expr="//page[@name='extra']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
        
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='note']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">1</attribute>
        </xpath>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it improves on the accepted answer, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.